# Why are .jpg's appearing yellow in my flash as3 application?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, jpeg

I retrieve .jpgs from my server and load them within my as3 app. I use Flash CS3, and am not using flex. Occasionally, some images will appear yellow and unreadable within the app. The actual original of the image is fine, and has no such yellowing, yet when I load the image in flash it appears yellow. This seems independent of size, cause I have large and small images that appear yellow, and some that do not with the app.

When looking at the images in flashplayer 9, this yellowing occurs. It always happens on the same ones, with the rest appearing as expected. When looking at the images in flashplayer 10, it NEVER has yellowing, all images appear as intended.

Comment: Are they saved in CMYK format?

Comment: Or 32-bit format? In other words, is there something different about the files that are working versus the ones that are not?

Comment: Thanks! It was cmyk that was the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect, like other people have said, it's something to do with the colour profile of the jpgs. It may be because FP10 has colour management, whereas FP9 does not:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/color_correction_as3/

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, we currently generate the .jpgs through a server side conversion tool, so I will run some tests with our other dev and post the results!

Comment: Thanks everyone for your input. Turns out our converter was converting into both cmyk and rgb jpgs. When we converted over our cmyk images to rgb the yellowing was gone within flash 9. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'll second the vote for color management, and ask if the JPEG in question is using the Adobe color space rather than SRGB?

Answer (score 1):

CMYK pictures with more than 72 dpi have this yellow look